# UIWebView in iphone4.0

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I use UIWebView in iphone4.0 show a html page,but can show one page and cannot scroll. after rotate iphone It can show all page and scroll normally ,this problem  is not exist in 3.1

Comment: Can you post some code or additional description? I have an app with a UIWebView, developed under 3.x, that compiled and ran just fine linked with 4.x.

Comment: I find this is a html page peoblem,and I modify the html,it's good !I think iphone4.0 UIWebView  core is updated!

Answer (score 0):

I find this is a html page peoblem,and I modify the html,it's good !I think iphone4.0 UIWebView core is updated!